# AWS S3 multipart upload javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, upload, multipart

I'm looking for an example implementation of the S3 multipart upload for very large files. I found a variety of halfway implementations online, but none that met my requirements.

Comment: I was also looking at this a few months ago.  I ended up modifying and making my own version of the Upload() AWS method.  I added pause/resume functionality as well as transparent handling of expiring credentials for long uploads.  [I made a separate question to highlight the needs I had, and answer in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76534516/how-to-pause-and-resume-multipart-uploads-for-large-files-using-aws-s3-v3-javasc/76534517#76534517)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and most memory efficient implementation i could come up with. I wish i could somehow use Promise.all() to speed up the uploading process, but i found it difficult to maintain the part order using a heavily asynch implementation. I tested this with 6GB files and directories.

```
const _ = require('underscore')
const mime = require('mime-types')
let AWS = require('aws-sdk/index');
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
let s3 = new AWS.S3();

async function multipartUploadFile(params, filePath) {
    console.log(`S3Helper: Beginning multipart upload of file ${params.Key} to ${params.Bucket}`)
    //First create the multipart upload ID
    let multipartCreateResult = await s3.createMultipartUpload({
        Bucket: params.Bucket,
        Key: params.Key,
        ContentType: mime.lookup(filePath),
        StorageClass: 'STANDARD'
    }).promise();
    console.log("S3Helper: multipartUploadFile createResult - ", multipartCreateResult)

    let chunkCount = 1;
    let CHUNK_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

    let uploadedParts = []
    //Read through the file, grab a chunk, and put it in an upload promise
    async function gatherChunks() {
        const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { highWaterMark: CHUNK_SIZE });
        for await(const data of stream) {
            // do something with data
            let etag = await s3.uploadPart({
                Body: data,
                Bucket: params.Bucket,
                Key: params.Key,
                PartNumber: chunkCount,
                UploadId: multipartCreateResult.UploadId,
            }).promise().then( (result) => {return result.ETag.toString()})
            uploadedParts.push({
                ETag: etag,
                PartNumber: chunkCount
            })
            chunkCount++;
        }
    }

    gatherChunks().then( () => {
        let sortedUploads = _.sortBy(uploadedParts, 'PartNumber')
        console.log("Sorted uploadedParts: ", sortedUploads)
        return s3.completeMultipartUpload({
            Bucket: params.Bucket,
            Key: params.Key,
            MultipartUpload: {
                Parts: sortedUploads
            },
            UploadId: multipartCreateResult.UploadId
        }).promise()
    })

}

let params = {
    Bucket: "someBucket",
    Key:  "someKey"
};

let filePath = "./someFilePath"

await multipartUploadFile(params, filePath);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my contribution to this question.

Thanks jim-chertkov, with your answer above, I was able to get this done.

The `promise.all` is working properly. I only have to order the results before sending to the `completeMultipartUpload`:

```
async multipartUploadFile({file, key}) {
  const { awsKey, secret, bucket } = this.retrieveConfigs()

  aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: awsKey,
    secretAccessKey: secret,
    region: 'sa-east-1',
  })

  const s3 = new aws.S3();

  const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
  };

  const upload = await s3.createMultipartUpload(uploadParams).promise();

  const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(file.toString('base64'));

  const partSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
  const parts = [];
  let offset = 0;
  while (offset < fileBuffer.length) {
    const part = Buffer.from(fileBuffer.slice(offset, offset + partSize));
    parts.push(part);
    offset += partSize;
  }

  const uploadedParts = [];
  const promises = parts.map(async (partData, index) => {
    const uploadPartParams = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: uploadParams.Key,
      UploadId: upload.UploadId,
      PartNumber: index + 1,
      Body: partData,
    };
    const part = await s3.uploadPart(uploadPartParams).promise()
    console.log('part', part)
    const { ETag } = part;
    uploadedParts.push({ PartNumber: index + 1, ETag: ETag });
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);
  const orderned = uploadedParts.sort(this.orderParts)

  console.log('orderned', orderned)

  const completeParams = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: uploadParams.Key,
    MultipartUpload: { Parts: orderned },
    UploadId: upload.UploadId,
  };

  console.log('completeParams', JSON.stringify(completeParams, null, 2))

  const complete = await s3.completeMultipartUpload(completeParams).promise()
  console.log('complete', complete)
  return complete
}
```

The logs are just to show whats happening.

Comment: For future readers : Above solution throws following exception : `The list of parts was not in ascending order. Parts must be ordered by part number.` To resolve it, you change `const orderned = uploadedParts.sort(this.orderParts)` to   `const orderned = uploadedParts.sort((a,b)=> a.PartNumber - b.PartNumber)`